# Change or toggle spacing between toc entries for individual groups of entries

Tags: spacing, table-of-contents, koma-script, titletoc

In my table of contents I have regular chapters with sections and subsections etc. and I have chapters as part of the preface and postface, which do not have any sections. The spacing between every group of chapters and sections ist always the same. However, I'd like to reduce the spacing between all the non-regular chapters, as I have to optimize the general composition of the toc.

So basically I look for a way to toggle a different spacing at some point in the toc. I hope the following MWE illustrates it.

### MWE

```
\documentclass{scrbook}

\usepackage{titletoc}

\begin{document}

\tableofcontents

\chapter{Regular Chapter 1}
\section{title}
\section{title}
\chapter{Regular Chapter 2}
\section{title}
\section{title}
\chapter{Regular Chapter 3}
\section{title}
\section{title}

\chapter{Postface Chapter 1 - spacing after entry should be reduced}
\chapter{Postface Chapter 2 - spacing after entry should be reduced}
\chapter{Postface Chapter 3 - spacing after entry can be reduced}

\end{document}
```

[image]

Any idea how I could achieve this?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can add a line to the TOC where you change the space with `\DeclareTOCStyleEntry[beforeskip=<space>]{default}{chapter}`

```
\documentclass{scrbook}

\begin{document}
    
    \tableofcontents
    
    \chapter{Regular Chapter 1}
        \section{title}
        \section{title}
    \chapter{Regular Chapter 2}
        \section{title}
        \section{title}
    \chapter{Regular Chapter 3}
        \section{title}
        \section{title}
    
    \chapter{Postface Chapter 1 - spacing after entry should be reduced}

  % Place this after the first chapter of the block
    \addtocontents{toc}{\DeclareTOCStyleEntry[beforeskip=1ex]{default}{chapter}} 

    \chapter{Postface Chapter 2 - spacing after entry should be reduced}
    \chapter{Postface Chapter 3 - spacing after entry can be reduced}
    
\end{document}
```

[image]

Comment: Exactly, what I was looking for. Thank you!